# Image size getting changed [ Increased/decreased ] after selecting from gallery/Camera?

Tags: android, image, camera, base64, gallery

***I have checked many similar posts but I was not able resolved these issues : -***

---

Issue 1 :

If I pick an image from the gallery and save the image in device external storage. The image is **saved as almost 3 times the size of the original image**.

Issue 2 :

If I click an image from Camera and save the image in device external storage. The image is **saved in very low quality**.

check the below screenshots.

[image]

I need to save the **exact** image in device storage and later upload the image in the base64 format.

[Code : github](https://github.com/ajaynonstopio/AndroidImageSaveUpload)

Comment: Can you post the code you have used to save the image?

Comment: I have share an link for the sample project repo :
https://github.com/ajaynonstopio/AndroidImageSaveUpload

Comment: For camera, you should only use getExtras("data") for preview. In both cases, don't save a Bitmap file, but use the compressed Jpeg file that you find in MediaStore (a.k.a. Gallery). Consider some upload method that can use binary file, because base64 for big pictures is too wasteful.

Answer (score 1):

When you take a photo you are retrieving the Bitmap using "...getExtras("data")..." but this field doesn't contains the REAL PICTURE location/Uri or Bitmap but only the one of a THUMBNAIL version. Please read this link: https://medium.com/@rodrigolmti/android-get-camera-thumbnail-and-full-image-1bddfdc5347e

Comment: But what about Issue 1 ?